# Replacing a column with a function of itself in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm currently lost deep inside the pandas documentation. My problem is this:

I have a simple dataframe

```
col1  col2
 1     A
 4     B 
 5     X
```

My aim is to apply something like:

```
 df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(square)
```

where square is a cleanly defined function.
But this operation throws an error warning (and produces incorrect results)

*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead*

I can't make sense of this nor the documentation it points to. My workflow is linear (in case this makes a wider range of solutions viable).

Pandas 0.17.1 and Python 2.7

All help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your function to your question?

Comment: The function MaxU gives would be sufficient. I'm wondering if this question breaches the "too broad" restriction for asks - and/or if I have some problems with my implementation which is causing it to throw the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it works properly for me (pandas 0.18.1):

```
In [31]: def square(x):
   ....:     return x ** 2
   ....:

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
   col1 col2
0     1    A
1     4    B
2     5    X

In [35]: df.col1 = df.col1.apply(square)

In [36]: df
Out[36]:
   col1 col2
0     1    A
1    16    B
2    25    X
```

PS it also might depend on the implementation of your function...

Comment: @draco_alpine, nope, no errors. But i'm using Python 3.5.1 and Pandas 0.18.1. I think the pandas version is much more important in this case. What pandas version do you have?

Comment: Sorry, being useless. I'm only on 0.17.1 - I had just assumed it had been updated...

Comment: Came back to this. It worked on a second attempt in 0.17.1 - problem was clearly me and not the solution given by MaxU

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.loc` command to get rid of the warning

```
df.loc[:'col1'] = df['col1'].apply(square)
```